# I am developing an Android application with cordova, I want to implement SMS composer in my app

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

I am using the following plugin for Cordova with `Android`:
$ cordova plugin add `cordova-sms-plugin`

I want to open default sms app in mobile using `cordova` app. I need to open sms app with mobile number and text after click button in `cordova`. Is this possible?
Here  is my code:-

```
in html:-
<input id="numberTxt" placeholder="Enter mobile number" value="" type="tel" />
<textarea id="messageTxt" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="app.sendSms()" value="Send SMS" />

In app.js:-
var app = {
    sendSms: function() {
        var number = document.getElementById('numberTxt').value.toString(); /* iOS: ensure number is actually a string */
        var message = document.getElementById('messageTxt').value;
        console.log("number=" + number + ", message= " + message);

        //CONFIGURATION
        var options = {
            replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
            android: {
                intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
                //intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app, require : android.permission.SEND_SMS and android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
            }
        };

        var success = function () { alert('Message sent successfully'); };
        var error = function (e) { alert('Message Failed:' + e); };
        sms.send(number, message, options, success, error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Did u solve the issue ?